# Punishment for bad karma after death also and after getting new body also?

Tags: karma, bhagavata-purana

I was reading this short story of [Ajamila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajamila) from hindu purana.

It was clearly stating that :

> The Yamadutas were bewildered. "Why are these effulgent and beautiful personalities checking our action? It's our duty to take sinful men to Yamaraja for punishment; then they are awarded another material body for the next life so that they can get the result of their sinful activity."

- Is this mean we get punish by yamaduta after death also and get results of sinful act in new birth also?
- Why these two kinds of punishments?

Comment: there is a mistaken assumption (even perhaps in the answers of the duplicate question). next life does not necessarily mean that life on Earth. there are billions and billions of lokas where souls get born and die there. If a jiva dies on earth, it may be born on another loka. That becomes its next birth. so yamaloka is another loka. the jiva being born in yamaloka, becomes its next birth. do u understand? there is no question of duplicate reactions. there is only one reaction. all the best sir!

Comment: law of karma is this: 'whatever you do, will come back to you, either in this life, or in the next life, or in a future life. It may be in this world, or the next world, or a totally different world. It may be exhausted completely in one life, or it may be so huge that it needs to exhausted through several lives. it may also be so negligble that it need not be reacted.' But there is a way to escape karma. Surrender. Surrender all our actions to Lord Sri Krishna (or Lord Shiva or the Ishta God ) the Satguru. Then we will be free from all karmas. All the best

Comment: @Sai sir would be glad if you could answer this.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/does-fruits-of-rajasi-or-tamasi-karma-also-has-categories