# Does fruits of rajasi or tamasi karma also has categories?

Tags: karma

By doing good kind of rajasi karma we gets good fruits.

But my question, is that fruits also has categories or we can get any kind of fruit?

Example If someone does the charity in terms of money (as a rajasi karma [with expectation in return]) then is he going to get returns in terms of money only or any kind of good fruit as a return he can get in his life?

If someone does seva of old age persons (same as rajasi karma) then is he going to get same fruit means good old age days in return or he may get another things?

Means do we get fruits according to category of karma we does or any thing?

Comment: it depends. sometimes it is same, sometimes it is different. there is no way to predict how karma will come back to you in future. Even great astrologists can only say 'something bad will happen, or you will gain something'. It is near impossible to get into specifics, because the nature of karma is such that it cannot be understood easily. Only God knows. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fruit is based on the type of Karma done. If karma done is sattvika, then the fruit will also be sattvika. But no guarantee that it will be the same as what you did. 
In your example above, if you donate 50 rupees to a beggar, it doesn't mean you will get 50 rupees back from someone else. But that karma will yield result in some other way, may be something like you might get a free meal somewhere in a strange city when you need the most. 
Also the fruit need not be enjoyed in earth only. By doing good karma, you can earn a good fortune to spend in heaven after death. So there in no guarantee in what form it comes back to us.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan 
Sources : Books by Swami Virajeshwara . Refer here : http://www.swami-virajeshwara.com/Reality-book.htm